# Passing two function in Parent

Tags: react-native

I have an issue with passing two functions from Child to Parent. 
Child functions are =>

```
setValueLocally = () => {...}
show_User_Poll = () => {...}
```

In Parent i am accessing these functions by making two more functions.

```
savePollData() { this.refs.savePoll.setValueLocally()  }

_show_User_Poll() { this.refs.showPoll.show_User_Poll() }
```

And i am rendering these functions in Parent.
Question is How can i set ref for above twofunctions ?

```
 <Child ref = {"savePoll", "showPoll"} />
```

I am doing this but it is giving error ..

for single function it works for me

```
 <Child ref="savePoll"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a reference on your child component and then you can access all the methods of the child, from Parent. 
PS: you can only reference class components so your Child needs to be a class.

```
const Parent = props => {
  const childRef = React.useRef(null);

  const savePollData = () => {
    childRef.current.savePollData();
  };

  const _show_User_Poll = () => {
    childRef.current.show_User_Poll();
  };

  return <Child ref={childRef} />;
};

class Child extends React.Component {
  setValueLocally = () => {
    return null;
  };

  show_User_Poll = () => {
    return null;
  };
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```